# SVG is a scrollable object in Safari

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, svg

Here's a page with an SVG graphic I designed.
http://s383324595.onlinehome.us/HTML5-1
It looks and acts properly in Chrome (and Canary and Chromium), but the graphic itself is a tiny, square in Safari 5.1, and requires scrolling to see the whole image. What's wrong?
Moreover, it looks like the graphic is on the offset on the X axis in Firefox. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the width and height attributes on the root <svg> element, then tweak the CSS for the embed element so that it gets the width and height you want.

Comment: What about the viewBox attribute? Does that one matter at all?

Comment: Disregard the above comment. It worked perfectly, thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Safari don't understand float numbers as width and height on root SVG element. Make sure they are integers (round them up).

Comment: I tried this and your answer doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: @RobertLongson You have to edit the source and change it here: <svg width="167"    height="37"></svg> with round up! Worked for me today:) so you have to be doing sth wrong

Comment: So you probably have some point out of "view port" or width x height canvas